# No such file or directory error?

Tags: python

I'm using someone else's code to rename files in a folder sequentially.

```
    import os
    _src = ("/Path/To/Directory")
    for i,filename in enumerate(os.listdir(_src)):
        newname = ('Test-' + str(i).zfill(3))
        os.rename(filename, newname)
        print('renaming "%s" to "%s"' % (filename,newname))
```

What is the error in the above snippet?

Comment: Put exactly what the error says in your comment.

Comment: Have you replaced `"/Path/To/Directory"` with the path to the directory you want to rename?

Comment: Yes I just didn't want to show my real directory haha.

Comment: Hi, Asori. What if you append the file path to the filename you're trying to change? If you're not in the directory then I don't think that's going to work. For example if you're running the script in `/usr/home/asori/my_project/`, but  the file is in `/usr/home` it's unable to find the file. nvm, Coldspeed answered it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying the fully qualified path when calling `os.rename`. You need:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(_src, filename), os.path.join(_src, newname))
```

Comment: (From version 3.3, you can specify directories directly without string manipulation.)